# How can I set a different CF instance to handle a subdirectory?

Tags: coldfusion

What I would like to do is have different CF instances process requests for the paths such as "domain.com", "domain.com/subdir", "domain.com/subdir2", etc. This is with CF8 Enterprise and IIS 7. It is easy enough to do if the domains are different between instances. I believe I have read about doing this with subfolders but can no longer find the necessary information. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: We just decided to go with a subdomain and redirecting the old path to the new for a period of time.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to manually adjust the handler mappings at the individual directory level to use the CF server instance you want. This would override the handler mappings from the root site, but isn't something you can configure with the `wsconfig.exe` tool that comes with CF.

I think you're far better off handling it with a separate domain, and separate IIS site.